# How to insert one xmldom object to a node of another xmldom object in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

How do I insert one xmldom object to a node of another xmldom object in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the node where you want:

```
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");

newNode=xmlDoc.createElement("book");

x=xmlDoc.documentElement;
y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book")[3];

x.insertBefore(newNode,y);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_nodes_add.asp